# Program to manage network profiles in Windows 7, possibly location-aware

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, software-rec, network-profiles

I'm looking for a program that will allow you to easily switch between networks on a laptop, when moving between networks, so that one can easily keep their static IP and dns setting for the specific network they are on.

I've seen programs like this before, but I can't think of any off the top of my head.  Are any programs like this location-aware now days? That would enable the avoidance of even having to press a button to switch network profiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Free IP Switcher](http://www.eusing.com/ipswitch/free_ip_switcher.htm):

> Free IP Switcher is a perfect solution for you. It switches between preconfigured network settings with a single click and without any reboot. With Free IP Switcher you can automatically change all network settings on your pc: IP address, network masks, default gateway, DNS server, wins server, proxy settings, default printer and more.

[image]

Or, as an alternative, you can try [NetSetMan](http://www.netsetman.com/):

> NetSetMan is a network settings manager which can easily switch between 6 different, visually structured profiles

[image]